# How to visualize images in Grafana coming from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, grafana

I would like to visualize the pictures that comes from SQL server data source in Grafana. The pictures are stored in varbinary(max) data type. I tried the SQL query below but Grafana is not able to visualize/render it. Is there a way to do that?

```
SELECT CAST(c_img AS IMAGE)
FROM tbl_test WHERE c_id = 8
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: FYI, the `image` data type has been deprecated since 2005; you really shouldn't be using it anymore.

Comment: The `IMAGE` data type, deprecated as already mentioned, has nothing to do with pictures. It's just a binary storage type that's accessed through handles like the also-deprecated `TEXT` and `NTEXT` data types.